# Workflow 2013 what does "Add to variable" means

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, power-automate, date-time

I am redesigning a Workflow 2013 to Power Automate and I have this action inside Workflow 2013:

[image]

So what this action do exactly? Thanks

Comment: It adds months, days, hours etc, to date variable.

Comment: @GaneshSanap ok thanks but it is not clear how many months it is adding ?

Comment: It is adding number of months stored in "Months To Complete" column in same list item/row for which designer workflow is running

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap so it is adding months to the "Months To Complete" field? but how many months it is adding?

Comment: It is adding number of months mentioned in "Months To Complete" field **to** Variable named as "Today" and storing results in another variable named "TargetCompletionDate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action shown in image you provided **Adds Time to Date** in SharePoint designer workflows.

| Action | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Add Time to Date | Adds a specific time in minutes, hours, days, or months to a date (Year is not supported), and stores the output value as a variable. The date can be a current data, specific date, or a lookup. The 'Current Date' value returns UTC midnight. |

---

In your case, it is adding number of months stored in **Months To Complete** column in same list item/row for which designer workflow is running.

Comment: @Ganesg Sanap but how i can know how many months it is adding? as it is not showing any variable beside the months

Comment: It is adding number of months mentioned in `Months To Complete` field **to** Variable named as `Today` and storing results in another variable named `TargetCompletionDate`. It is not updating any column in list item.